# Pull two columns from Excel and append key value pairs to dictionary

Tags: python, excel, pandas

My apologies if similar questions have been asked -- I dug through quite a few, but they did not match my specific issue.

Basically, I have an Excel spreadsheet with 2 columns; Name and Email. I'm using `pandas` to grab the two columns from the file. I want to grab the values from the columns in order, and append them to a dictionary so that I can easily reference name and email pairs later on.

I currently have two functions in two files. One is my `main` file/function, and the other is a file named `readExcel` with a function named `read`:

```
# readExcel.py
import pandas as pd

def read(fileName: str, sheetName: str):
    f = pd.read_excel(fileName, sheet_name = sheetName)
    return f

# __main__.py
import readExcel as re

from pathlib import Path

def main():
    contacts = {}

    p = Path(__file__).with_name('contacts.xlsx')
    f = re.read(p, "Sheet1")

    for n in f["Name"]:
        for e in f["Email"]:
            contacts[n] = e

    print(contacts)
```

The issue I'm facing here is that the resulting dictionary is un-ordered, e.g., `Bob Testerson: jim.tester@gmailcom, Jim Tester: bob.testerson@gmail.com`

How would I go about properly ordering the data I'm pulling from the spreadsheet?

EDIT: Per request, I'll add more information regarding the Excel file and preferred order.

The Excel file looks like this:
[Excel image preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N129O.png)

As for the ordering of the data, it seems it would be best done before adding it to the dictionary, but that's not a requirement for me. Also, I don't specifically care about the order in which the key / value pairs appear in the dictionary, but rather that the key /values pairs appear as they do in the Excel file, e.g.,

```
{
    "Jon Testerson": "jon.test@gmail.com", 
    "Henry": "henrytest@gmail.com", 
    "Bryce Testington": "brycetestington@gmail.com", 
    "Greg": "greg_test@yahoo.com", 
    "Jerry Testerfield", "jerrytester@hotmail.com"
}
```

Comment: What does the data look like in the columns that you are pulling can you show an example i.e. is it always a First & Last Name, or sometimes only one of those?

Are you trying to order the data in the dictionary after pulling it or prior?  What is the order you desire?  Alphabetical by email address in the values? i.e. Show an example of the incorrect order and correct order.

Comment: I will update the description to include an example of the excel file as well as additional information about the data and preferred order.

Comment: Are you doing anything with the DataFrame? Do you have to use Pandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this using the pandas to dict method.  Just change the column names if you need to.

```
import pandas as pd

def read_excel(path_to_file):

    df = pd.read_excel(path_to_file)

    return df

def dataframe_to_dict(df, key_column, value_column):

    name_email_dict = df.set_index(key_column)[value_column].to_dict()

    return name_email_dict

if __name__ == "__main__":

    path_to_file = 'C:\projects\scratchwork\excel_dict.xlsx'

    df = read_excel(path_to_file)

    name_email_dict = dataframe_to_dict(df,'Name','Email')

    print(name_email_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's an easier way to do it but I would put the data into a data frame and then use the sort_values method to sort them. This would look something like:

```
# readExcel.py
import pandas as pd

def read(fileName: str, sheetName: str):
  f = pd.read_excel(fileName, sheet_name = sheetName)
  return f

# __main__.py
import readExcel as re

from pathlib import Path

def main():
  df = pd.DataFrame()
  contacts = {}

 p = Path(__file__).with_name('contacts.xlsx')
 f = re.read(p, "Sheet1")
 df = df.append(f,ignore_index=True)

print(df.sort_values(by=["Name","Email"]))
```

Again may not be the best way to do it but it should work if there is extra information on Sheet 1 then prior to the print I would do:

```
df = df[['Name','Email']]
```

Which would then only select name and email